# Can I visit my partner, according to current restrictions in the UK?

Tags: united-kingdom, covid-19

I currently live 10+ miles apart from my partner. I do not go indoors with them, I as I walk around their neighbourhood and chat with them, all the while wearing a mask and attempting to keep distance between other people and us. My partner is classified as Extremely Clinicially Vulnerable, and as such I *could* be classed as their carer while I spend time with them. If I was stopped by a police officer, would it be a reasonable excuse that I am exercising with my extremely clinically vulnerable partner, who does not leave their house apart from to exercise?
Or is this illegal by law?

National Lockdown restrctions - https://www.gov.uk/guidance/national-lockdown-stay-at-home?priority-taxon=774cee22-d896-44c1-a611-e3109cce8eae
Extremely Vulnerable advice - https://www.gov.uk/coronavirus-shielding-support?priority-taxon=774cee22-d896-44c1-a611-e3109cce8eae

Comment: "Extremely clinically vulnerable" has little to no corelation with needing a carer. The former refers entirely to COVID. Does your partner actually have a reason to need you as a carer or are you looking for excuses?

Comment: When is current? Restrictions change about weekly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact that your partner is extremely clinically vulnerable makes it **more** important that you avoid contact. This does not allow you any special privileges to see them.

If you were actually their carer, this would be different.

If one or both of you live alone (i.e. are the only adult in your household) and neither of you are part of a support bubble, you can form a support bubble with each other. As part of a support bubble you would treat each other as part of the same household in most respects and would be able to see each other and even stay overnight.